# Coded UI Cross browser does not work in Chrome/Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, cross-browser, coded-ui-tests

I used the **BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = "Chrome"**("firefox") to run my test cases in chrome (firefox) and i installed "Cross Browser Selenium Components" also.
But I am getting error in the following statement "**BrowserWindow.Launch(new System.Uri(DevicesCenterURL))**

It will launch chrome browser with data; in address bar and also showing in command line as follows
"Starting ChromeDriver  on port 25278
Only local connections are allowed".

please find the attached image[image]

I am using vs 2013 and Selenium 2.43.1

Is there any work around? Can you please guide me the correct approach.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you unblocked the Dlls as mentioned here https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/11cfc881-f8c9-4f96-b303-a2780156628d. Sometime this causes lot of pain while executing test cases.